# How to write SQL if row exists in both ways

Tags: sql

looking to filter a table for Facebook Ads.

Currently I have a naming convention for campaigns either containing the string 'test' or does not contain the string 'test' in the campaign name.

How can I manipulate the filters rows that exist in both testing campaigns and non-testing campaigns and only ones that exist in both?

Example query for only 'test' campaigns

```
SELECT `ads` 
FROM `facebook_ads`
WHERE `campaign_name` LIKE '%test%'
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you are asking. Do you mean you have a name like `OldDudesWhoLikeCoding` and `OldDudesWhoLikeTestCoding`?

Comment: Please provide enough sample data, and the expected outcomes from that sample data, to illustrate your use cases